# Using Javascript function to hide button inside PHP

Tags: javascript, php, function

I am currently writing a website where I want to hide the the supervisor editing button if the supervisor field = N. I am able to get the query to display the correct output but I can't get the button to hide. Can anyone help me get it to hide whenever the page loads. I also under stand I should be using PDO's but we have not been taught that sadly.

HTML & PHP

```
        <?php

        $supervisorstatus = mysql_fetch_assoc($supervisorresult);
        echo $supervisorstatus['supervisor'];
                                if($supervisorstatus !='Y') {
                                    echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
     'closesup();',
     '</script>'
;
                                } 


        ?>
```

JavaScript

```
function closesup(){
    document.getElementById('supervisor').style.visibility="hidden";
}
```

Supervisor is the element id for the button.

Comment: Check my answer it solves your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how your code would be

```
    <?php

            $supervisorstatus = mysql_fetch_assoc($supervisorresult);
            echo $supervisorstatus['supervisor'];
                                    if($supervisorstatus['supervisor'] !='Y') {
                                        echo '<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#supervisor").hide();
});
</script>';        

                                    } 


            ?>
```

I gave a example of implementation above but if you need to see it separate Here is the code to hide your supervisor id

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#supervisor").hide();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$supervisorstatus` contains an array. You probably want: `if($supervisorstatus['supervisor'] !='Y') {`

Comment: Well you should keep this new line in there, because your current one is checking to see if an array is equal to a string, which will always be false.